# Embedding a binary file inside a class library

Tags: c#, binary, embedding

Is it possible to embed a custom binary file inside a C# class library and then at runtime read it with a binary reader?

I'm guessing it might be possible through resources.

Many thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do this by adding the file to the Resources through the project properties.  Visual studio will then give you a handy class to access your file using the following code

```
byte[] theFile = myNamespace.Properties.Resources.theBinaryFile;
```

Where the resource name is theBinaryFile.

Comment: RE: my comment on the answer below. If the original file changes will it be re-embedded automatically when I next build the project?

Comment: yes if you change the file the next build will update the resource file.

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is easy:

Add the file to your project and set the "Build action" to "Embedded resource".

In your program do

```
foreach (string name in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames())
{
  if (name.EndsWith("<name>", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
  {
    using (Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(name))
    {
      // ...
    }
    break;
  }
}
```

Finding the right resource is a little bit complicating because there is stuff in front of the file name (namespaces etc. set a breakpoint to the if(...) to see the real resource name).

Comment: This works great. Especially as I am constantly changing the file contents and it just re-embeds when I build the project.