# How do i use a file from the resources folder with a string path (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, resources

I am trying to use a send file function that I don't have control of changing. It wants the file to be found from the PC through a string. I got it working if i just put the file in a sub-folder with my program, but i was wondering if i could put the file in the resources folder in order to embed this file into the program. This is what I am having difficulty with, thanks.

Comment: If the function requires a physical file path, then embedded resources won't work without your extracting that resource to a physical location (such as a temp file).

Comment: ok ill try that. thanks

Comment: You could embed the file then extract it once the first time the program runs.  You will run into rights issues if you try to extract it to a Program Files folder but you could use Users > (User name) > AppData > Local > (Company) > (Programname)

Comment: I think alternative approach will solve your problem - Embedding a binary file ⇨ https://stackoverflow.com/q/891958/3645638